# OpenCSV Not reading next line if previous line ends with "

Tags: java, escaping, double-quotes, opencsv, csvreader

I have a CSV in the below format.

```
id,name,address,city

ABC,"DE""F",HIJ,"KLM""N"

OPQ,RST,"U""V","WXYZ"""
```

I am using OpenCSV to read the file. But City is reading KLM"N along with next line.

Eg: City is getting read like

```
KLM"N

OPQ,RST,U etc.
```

But OPQ should be id of the next record. I tried using withQuoteChar('"') but it did not work. Is there any other way to resolve this?

I tried the below code.

```
csvReader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String[] record = csvReader.readNext();
        
while ((record = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
 MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
   entity.setID(record[0]);
   entity.setName(record[1]);
   entity.setAddress(record[2]);
   entity.setCity(record[3]);
```

}

Also tried the below snippet.
try (CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
.withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder().withQuoteChar('"').build().build()){}

Comment: You need, at the very least, to post the offending part of the file formatted as code, but preferably to post a link to reproducible data

Comment: are `OPQ,RST,"U""V","WXYZ"""` on the same line as `ABC,"DE""F",HIJ,"KLM""N"`? Typically, different records are on different rows. Do you own the file, i.e. can you change the way it gets generated?

Comment: @user2340612 OPQ,RST,"U""V","WXYZ""" is in the next row. Apologies, updated the question. No, I dont own the file. I receive it from a different datasource. Just curious if there is any way to resolve this.

Comment: I just tried running the code you pasted and I can correctly read `ABC, DE"F, HIJ, KLM"N` and `OPQ, RST, U"V, WXYZ"` as separate records. I used opencsv v5.9